# Setting delegate - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, delegates

i have some problems with delegates under xcode while programming an application for Mac OS. I want to communicate with mobile phones if they are in the same network via TCP. I have the following server integrated in my project:

https://github.com/tuscland/osc-echo-example/blob/master/TCPServer.m

https://github.com/tuscland/osc-echo-example/blob/master/TCPServer.h

The only thing I changed at the server is that I extended the start-method so that I can specify a special port. Also I changed the TCPServerDelegation in TCPServer.h to @protocol.

Now I want to set the delegate to this class. But then I get the following error:

> [MobileSync copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109e0f950

I tried a lot but I could not found any solution.

Here is my code, some irrelevant functions are taken out:

**MobileSync.h**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "TCPServer.h"

    @interface MobileSync: NSObject <TCPServerDelegation> {
    }

    -(id)init;
    -(void)StartServer:(int)port;
    -(void)StopServer;

    // Properties

    @end
```

**MobileSync.m**

```
    #import "MobileSync.h"
    #import "TCPServer.h"

    @implementation MobileSync {
        TCPServer *tcpServer;
        // Other variables
    }

    -(id)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self != nil) {
            // Fill variables with values
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)StartServer:(int)port {
        tcpServer = [[TCPServer alloc] init];
        [tcpServer setDelegate:self] // <<<<<<< This line is broken

        NSError *__autoreleasing* error = NULL;
        if ([tcpServer start:port error:error]) {
            NSLog(@"Server started successfully");
        }
    }

    -(void)StopServer {
        if (tcpServer.stop)
            NSLog(@"Server stoped successfully");
    }

    // different sync functions

    // tcpServer Delegate function
    -(void)TCPServer:(TCPServer *)server didReceiveConnectionFromAddress:(NSData *)addr inputStream:(NSInputStream *)istr outputStream:(NSOutputStream *)ostr {
        NSLog(@"Connection received.");
    }
```

**TCPServer.h**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

    NSString * const TCPServerErrorDomain;

    typedef enum {
        kTCPServerCouldNotBindToIPv4Address = 1,
        kTCPServerCouldNotBindToIPv6Address = 2,
        kTCPServerNoSocketsAvailable = 3,
    } TCPServerErrorCode;

    @interface TCPServer : NSObject {
    @private
        id delegate;
        NSString *domain;
        NSString *name;
        NSString *type;
        uint16_t port;
        CFSocketRef ipv4socket;
        CFsocketRef ipv6socket;
        NSNetService *netService;
    }

    @property (readwrite, copy) id delegate;
    @property (readwrite, copy) NSString *domain;
    @property (readwrite, copy) NSString *name;
    @property (readwrite, copy) NSString *type;
    @property (readwrite) uint16_t port;

    -(BOOL)start:(int)port error:(NSError **)error;
    -(BOOL)stop;
    -(void)handleNewConnectionFromAddress:(NSData *)addr inputStream:(NSInputStream *)istr outputStream:(NSOutputStream *)ostr;

    @end

    @protocol TCPServerDelegation

        -(void)TCPServer:(TCPServer *)server didReceiveConnectionFromAddress:(NSData *)addr inputStream:(NSInputStream *)istr outputStream:(NSOutputStream *)ostr;

    @end
```

Can someone help me solving the problem? That would be great

Comment: Why is the `delegate` set with `copy`? When you assign the `delegate` to `self`, your `self classObject` don't know `copyWithZone` That's why there is an error. Usually, with custom delegate, we set `weak`. It was to `assign` on the original version.

Comment: Damn, completely forget that I changed that. That was it, thanks. Hat changed that because assign hat thrown an error.